# Iterating JSON with embedded array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "selected": true,
        "question": "Which of the following does <b><i>not</i></b> describe Washington’s location?",
        "answers": {
            "A": {
                "selector": "A",
                "answerText": "It is in the northwest corner of the United States.",
                "correct": "N"
            },
            "B": {
                "selector": "B",
                "answerText": "The Pacific Ocean provides the western border.",
                "correct": "N"
            },
            "C": {
                "selector": "C",
                "answerText": "It is north of Oregon and west of Idaho.</span>",
                "correct": "N"
            },
            "D": {
                "selector": "D",
                "answerText": "A natural boundary can be created by a river.",
                "correct": "Y"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "selected": true,
        "question": "Which of the following best describes a spatial pattern in Washington?",
        "answers": {
            "A": {
                "selector": "A",
                "answerText": "Most people settled along rivers and water in the fertile valleys.",
                "correct": "Y"
            },
            "B": {
                "selector": "B",
                "answerText": "Most people settled high in the mountains to protect themselves from their enemies.",
                "correct": "N"
            },
            "C": {
                "selector": "C",
                "answerText": "Most people settled at the base of the Rocky Mountains. They couldn’t travel any further.",
                "correct": "N"
            },
            "D": {
                "selector": "D",
                "answerText": "Most people settled along the Pacific Rim because it was a good place to trade.",
                "correct": "N"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

What is the best way to iterate through the object? Should I use jquery or straight javascript? Any example would be great...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse a JSON string to an object use

```
JSON.parse(str);
```

To iterate through an array, use

```
for(var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; ++i) {
    // Here use arr[i]
}
```

To iterate through an object, use

```
for(var i in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        // Here use obj[i]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am particular to `$.parseJSON` as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) and [here](http://runnable.com/UhY_jE3QH-IlAAAP/how-to-parse-a-json-file-using-jquery).